# Hadoop JobRunner do not launch job

Tags: spring, hadoop, mapreduce, cloudera

I started recently with Hadoop, and some problems came up at the very first moment, I've been able to work out with them thus far, but there is one that I have not been able to overcome with. The thing is, everything seems to be working fine, but when I try to launch a Hadoop job, it just gets hung up, and I don't know how manage to get this working, the execution frame is as follows:

```
13/05/22 20:02:43 INFO support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@3fe9029b: startup date [Wed May 22 20:02:43 CEST 2013]; root of context hierarchy
13/05/22 20:02:43 INFO xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [hadoop-configuration.xml]
13/05/22 20:02:43 INFO config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer: Loading properties file from class path resource [hadoop.properties]
13/05/22 20:02:43 INFO support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@2d062bb6: defining beans [org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer#0,hadoopConfiguration,foundation-job,JulianSchJobRunner]; root of factory hierarchy
13/05/22 20:02:44 INFO config.PropertiesFactoryBean: Loading properties file from class path resource [hadoop.properties]
13/05/22 20:02:44 INFO mapreduce.JobRunner: Starting job [foundation-job]
```

I also have to say that I'm using CDH4 from Cloudera, and Spring for Hadoop.

As I said at the final line, it stops and does not go ahead executing.
Thanks in advance guys

Ok, I've been looking around on logs and it launchs some exceptions:

```
2013-05-22 21:01:36,254 WARN org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker: Writing to file hdfs://localhost.localdomain:8020/tmp/mapred/system/jobtracker.info failed!
2013-05-22 21:01:36,254 WARN org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker: FileSystem is not ready yet!
2013-05-22 21:01:36,262 WARN org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker: Failed to initialize recovery manager. 
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File /tmp/mapred/system/jobtracker.info could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 1 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.
```

This problem could be related with permissions on HDFS, or otherwise they have nothing to do with it?

Comment: Check the logs for the name node and data node(s) for any exception messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, solved, for any future lookup, I have to say that the problem was solve by changing these directory file paths, to a mounting point with more memory assigned(The problem was NN is low on memory):

```
dfs.name.dir=${HOME}/path-to-desired-location instead of the basepath stated by default:
dfs.name.dir=/dfs/nn
```

And I also have to do the very same thing on both datanode and secondarynamenode too, and then just have to format the namenode and restart the HDFS service:

```
hdfs namenode -format
```

Hope this helps to anyone else, cheers